# Using dynamic SQL statement in Python 3

Tags: python, mysql

I have a SQL statement to use in a MySQL database in my Python3 code. The code is as follows:

```
price = "1"
high = "2"
low = "3"

mycursor.execute("""
    UPDATE
        currency_price_fact
    SET
        %s = %s,
        %s = %s,
        %s = %s
    WHERE currency_symbol = 'USD_gov'
                 """,(price,dict["USD_gov"]["p"].replace(",",""),high,dict["USD_gov"]["h"].replace(",",""),low,dict["USD_gov"]["l"].replace(",",""),))
```

But i am getting an error saying

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

I think i know what is going on here, i am passing `'1' = '4432'` instead of `1 = '4432'` but i do not know how to solve it.

Comment: `1 = '4432'` isn't a valid set clause either. Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Try `SET price = %s` instead of `SET %s = %s`, and change the arguments accordingly

Comment: You can't use parameterization on field names, only on the values. You need to build the query in two stages: set the field names with string formatting (and ensure you have some kind of sanitisation process for that) and then use parameterization on the values.

Comment: Before executing cursor, first print the statement via print command in code to get the complete mysql statement, to check statement.

Comment: @Suresh you can't do that. This is not normal string interpolation.